# Huber-M estimator for Robust Linear Regression R Vs Python

Tags: python, r, regression, linear-regression, robust

For Robust Linear regression in R using package Huber-M estimator, we use the below code:

```
rlm(x,y, weight,init='ls' psi=psi.huber, scaler.est=c('MAD'), method=c('M), maxit=50)
```

Is there any similar package in Python?

Comment: Do you mean Huber Regressor in scikit? An example to calculate it can be found her, later in the post: https://machinelearningmastery.com/robust-regression-for-machine-learning-in-python/